# show("show") não funciona no firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

`show("show")` não esta funcionando no firefox. Esse mesmo código funciona no chrome.

O que estaria de errado?

```js
$('#conteudo').hide();

<?php if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) { ?>
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
  event.preventDefault(); 
  $("#form").hide("slow"); 
  $("#conteudo").show("slow"); 
 });
<?php } ?>

$('#mostrar').click(function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 $("#form").show("show");
 $("#conteudo").hide("show");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="btn btn-success" id="mostrar"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i> Gerar outro</a>

<div class="form-actions clearfix" id="form">
<form action="relatorioGeralDetalhado.php" method="post" name="form1" id="form1" class="form-inline" role="form">
 <label class="inline">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" required name="date-range-picker" id="id-date-range-picker-1" placeholder="Selecione a data" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" />
 </label>
 <button type="submit" id="button" name="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm gerar"><i class="icon-save bigger-110"></i> Gerar</button>
 <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form1" />
</form>
</div>

<table class="table table-hover" id="conteudo">
tabela aqui.
</table>
```

O que seria esse erro?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: não é pra ser .show("slow") ?

Answer (score 5):

O seu código tem um erro de referência em:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    event.preventDefault(); 
    $("#form").hide("slow"); 
    $("#conteudo").show("slow"); 
});
```

Neste momento, `event` não está definido.

Remova está linha:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

No seu handler do click, mude de "show" para "slow":

```
$('#mostrar').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#form").show("slow");
    $("#conteudo").hide("slow");
})
```

Comment: Amigão, renomear para qual nome?

Comment: Remova a linha `event.preventDefault();`, ela não é usada no *ready*.

Comment: @SergioGarcia Por que no chrome funciona e no firefox não ? será que no chrome a função `ready` possui event ?

Comment: O código do ready gera erro para mim no chrome também (`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined(…)`)

Comment: E tanto `$("#form").show("slow");` quanto `$("#form").show("show");` funcionam em ambos os browsers.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    event.preventDefault(); 
    $("#form").hide("slow"); 
    $("#conteudo").show("slow"); 
});
```

Neste momento você ainda não definiu event (e na verdade nem faz sentido esse event.preventDefault no ready do body).

Answer (score 0):

Olá, obrigado a todos...
Sabe aquele momento de distração, faz as coisas mas não presta atenção no que esta na tela... kkkk

**Corrigir**, era bem simples.

1º) Tinha esquecido de colocar um `else` e colocar o `$('#conteudo').hide();`, dentro dele.

2º) Não precisava usar o `event.preventDefault();`, nem sei o porque tinha colocado ele...rsrsrs

Agradeço a todos pela enorme ajuda, se não fossem vocês, não teria atentado ao meu erro.

Grato a todos!